# Flex 2.5.35 yy_scan_buffer not initializing line and column numbers

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm using flex 2.5.35 and bison 2.7 (though this is a flex issue, I believe, so I've omitted parser.y)

My Flex grammar is very simple:

lexer.l

```
%{
#define YY_NO_INPUT
#include "parser.h"

#define YY_USER_ACTION yylloc->first_line = yylloc->last_line = yylineno; \
    yylloc->first_column = yycolumn; yylloc->last_column = yycolumn + (int)yyleng - 1; \
    yycolumn += (int)yyleng;

%}

%option yylineno
%option outfile="lexer.c" header-file="lexer.h"
%option warn
%option reentrant noyywrap never-interactive nounistd
%option nounput
%option bison-bridge
%option bison-locations

%%

[ \n\r\t]*               { /* Skip blanks. */ }
[A-Za-z0-9_\-@]+       { yylval->value = strdup(yytext); return TOKEN_VAR; }
"&&"                   { return TOKEN_AND; }
"||"                   { return TOKEN_OR; }
"!"                    { return TOKEN_NOT; }
"("                    { return TOKEN_LPAREN; }
")"                    { return TOKEN_RPAREN; }

%%
```

When scanning a string the values for line and column number were uninitialized garbage. I traced through the code and added the following lines to yy_scan_buffer in the generated lexer.c:

```
b->yy_bs_lineno = 1;
b->yy_bs_column = 1;
```

Now the values are as expected.

Is this a bug? `yy_create_buffer` initializes these fields correctly, but `yy_scan_buffer` doesn't.

Can't I use `%option yylineno` when parsing strings?

Is there a work around, or do I really need to modify the generated lexer.c?

Answer (score 3):

Yep I can confirm, that this is an issue with bison. It happen to me, I've fixed it by initializing them in my "compiler function"

```
void myParseFunction(const char* code, ...){
    yyscan_t myscanner;
    yylex_init(&myscanner);
    struct yyguts_t * yyg = (struct yyguts_t*)myscanner;

    yy_delete_buffer(YY_CURRENT_BUFFER,myscanner);
    yy_scan_string(code, myscanner);

    // [HACK] Those are not properly initialized for non file parsers
    // and becuase of that we get garbage in yyerror...
    yylineno = 1;
    yycolumn = 0;

    bool nasi = yyparse(myscanner, <your_args>);
        yylex_destroy(myscanner);
        return nasi;
}
```

Note that yylineno and yycolumn work just fine with reentrant parsers as they are defined as marcos that refer to "yyg".

Comment: This does not work properly when it is in another file (`yylineno` is not defined), what worker for me is `yyset_lineno(1, scanner); yyset_column(0, scanner);` right after call to `yy_scan_bytes`.

Answer (score 1):

You propably copied your YY_USER_ACTION code from "Adding Locations to the Lexer" part of [oreilly book](http://oreilly.com/linux/excerpts/9780596155971/error-reporting-recovery.html)

I believe you forgot to add `int yycolumn = 1;` before definition of YY_USER_ACTION, as it is done in code example in the link.

Comment: So, I saw that in the example and put it in originally. However, perhaps because of the configuration options, this would not compile. `yycolumn` is not an integer, but a macro, and at that point it is not assignable to.